# Discard annotations pdftron - Windows Store

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, pdftron, pdfnet

Im trying to do a discard annotations button on a page that display a pdf and has a toolbar to add annotations.

I would like to have the option of after adding some annotations, the user could revert to the original file, removing all annotations he did.

I tried finding a variable that saved a list of the annotations made but haven't found anything of sort.

Is there a way to discard all annotations made, or a place i can see the annotations that were created ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no built in mechanism for this. Instead you would track the added annotations by their unique ID (GUID), and/or Object number (SDFObj.GetObjNum).

Note, we will be releasing a full undo/redo API in an upcoming release, but it is still some months away. If you can, perhaps you could postpone this until our API is available.

Comment: I ended up creating a copy of original document, and replacing annotated document If the discard button was pressed